# drupal rewrite field as e-mail address

Tags: drupal, url-rewriting

I have the following scenario in Drupal 7:

- custom content type
- two fields (X and Y)
- I want to rewrite Y as an e-mail link with the subject as the text entered in field X

Answer (score 0):

The way *I* would do this is to rewrite the results as a contextual block view, and make that view appear on that content type via context.

Pre-requisites:

- **Context**: Filter view to appear only for that content type
- **Views**: To display the email field in the content type, rewritten results.
- **Token**: Does the grunt work in using your field variables and applying them in the rewritten mark up.

Steps:

1. Set Display of field 'Y' to hidden in the Content Type management of display.
2. Create a block view, call it "Custom Email" or something. Go to *Advanced > Contextual Filters*. Add *Content: Custom Content Type* as a contextual filter so you may reference variable from the current content type in you view.
3. Add fields *Content: Field X* and *Content: Field Y*, setting field X to **Exclude from Display**.
4. In field Y (your email field), uncheck labels etc and click *'Rewrite results'*
5. Simple markup with appropriate token field could be used as follows:

   `<a href="mailto:[y]?subject=[x]">[y]</a>`

   The token variables will represent the neccessary field variables to be used in the mark-up.
6. Finally, create a context and place your block view in the content area of your content type.

The are other implementations of this use case, such as using the EVA module to display the contextual views for the mark up however you want.